How can I prevent Helm from switching to root directory after typing forward slash?
I quite like the feature in helm-find-files where typing ~ takes me to my home directory.
What I don't like, however, is that typing / takes me to the root directory. I sometimes type this forward slash by mistake and it ruins my file finding, forcing me to start all over again.
I wonder if there is some way where I can retain the ~ functionality but disable /.
If that is not possible I would rather disable both together. Can someone please could let me know how I can improve this behaviour?

I don't know anything about Helm, other than it is a completion framework, but I doubt very much that it is switching directories. What happens if you delete the / that you typed by mistake?

@NickD it's not switching the directory visited, it's changing the directory offered in a minibuffer completion.

@Tyler so deleting the / and typing the correct thing would reset everything properly, correct? I just don't understand why the OP says "it ruins my file finding, forcing me to start all over again".

Just guessing, but I think that means it ruins the file path they are building in the helm completion prompt, not the actual file they are editing. Meaning they have to start over with the file completion, not the whole file. If they do ruin the actual file, that's a much bigger, different problem.

Well, if it does ruin the file path (i.e. it cannot be corrected by just deleting the incorrect /) then that would qualify as a bug in my book. But I don't use Helm so I'm not sure what the OP is seeing: I was hoping they would clarify.

There doesn't appear to be a way to disable the behaviour of / in helm-find-files. This is part of the built-in navigation features.
If you happen to hit it by accident, the completion buffer will update to the root directory, as you describe. You can't undo this, but if you enter ./ it will update the completion target to the default directory. In most cases this is the directory you started in (i.e., where the file you are currently editing is found). That might save you a step or two in recreating the path you want.
